# Virtual mint 19 Linux hard drive is resized with now mount point

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, mount, linux-mint

My virtual mint 19 100 GB was almost full. So I had to add additional disk space. I managed to extra 42 GB and 8 GB swap disk space. But it is not mounted correctly. I am not sure where or how to mount it to use this space. Here is the output from the df -h

[image]

The gparted show the partition as follows:-

[image]

Please let me how can I mount this /dev/sda2 and where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need as root to create a mount point: for Debian-based distributions this should be in `/media` as the preferred location.

Now you can mount `/dev/sda2` with the `mount` command:

```
mount /dev/sda2 /media/MountPoint    ;# (or whatever mount point you created)
```

You can make the mount point permanent by adding to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda2  /media/MointPoint  ext4  errors=remount-ro  0  1
#                             (or any other file system on /dev/sda2 instead of ext4)
```

Alternatively, you can move an entire directory (eg `/home/*`) to the new disc and then mount `/dev/sda2` there. In this case the `/etc/fstab` entry would be:

```
/dev/sda2  /home  ext4  errors=remount-ro  0  1
```

Once `/dev/sda2` is mounted there you can remove the original mount point.

However, in all honesty, I wouldn't do any of this: I'd delete `/dev/sda2` and use `gparted` to expand `/dev/sda1` to fill the free space. Doing that frees you from making decisions about which drive should hold which data.

It goes without saying that you should back up your virtual disc before doing any partition modifications.

Comment: I was trying to extend my virtual disk size by following this: https://tvi.al/resize-sda1-disk-of-your-vagrant-virtualbox-vm/ . Then I end up in this seatuation. Can tell what is the correct way of extending virtual disk size?

Comment: You have already extended the disc space. What you need to do is extend the partition `/dev/sda1`. In `gparted` simply grab the right-hand edge and drag until it is adjacent to the swap partition.

Comment: I started Gparted GUI as root. It doesn't allow me to drag or do any modification. I never used Gparted. So I  don't know am I doing it correctly or not. Can you please tell me what could be wrong?

Comment: You can't modify a live partition: you need to use an external Live Boot disc and run `gparted` from there.

Comment: So I have to boot by the Gparted live cd/iso. I will try this way.

Comment: I couldn't do it. I explain more with the picture here https://superuser.com/questions/1401082/how-to-marge-2-disk-partition-into-1-without-losing-existing-data-in-linux Kindly check and let me how to do it?

Comment: You need to copy any data from `/dev/sda2`, then delete it, so that you can now extend `/dev/sda1` and merge the contents of `/dev/sda2` from the copy.