# how to marge 2 disk partition into 1 without losing existing data In Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, gparted

First of all, I had less disk space in my virtual so I tried to extend my disk by some tutorial. Then I end up in this kind of situation:-
[Virtual mint 19 Linux hard drive is resized with now mount point](https://superuser.com/questions/1399032/virtual-mint-19-linux-hard-drive-is-resized-with-now-mount-point)

As you can see there are 2 partitions /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2 . I extended and made extra space. /dev/sda2 isn't mounted yet. So it is useless. Now I would like to merge /dev/sda2 with /dev/sda1. I have important data in /dev/sda1. So I can't format it. Here I boot it with Gparted live iso. But I don't see any way to drag the partition as suggested by AFH.

[image]

If I click Resize/Move:-

[image]

Please let me know how can I do it?

Comment: Why don't you just delete `/dev/sda2` and then extend `/dev/sda1` [like AFH suggested](https://superuser.com/a/1399052/83694)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Virtual mint 19 Linux hard drive is resized with now mount point](https://superuser.com/questions/1399032/virtual-mint-19-linux-hard-drive-is-resized-with-now-mount-point)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice.